# I need to take the e-mail from the login screen to come with me to go to the account page using session

Tags: php

So when a customer fills in their e-mail I would like to take that e-mail and use it to display their account information and orders. (Some stuff is in dutch, if you need something translated let me know). BTW first time posting let me know

```
<?php
session_start();
include("functies.php");
include("header.php");


?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css" type="text/css"/>
<div align="center">

<?php logo() ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-login">
          <form action="homepagina.php" method="post">
        <div align="center"><h4>Welkom terug!</h4></div>
        <p align ="left">E-mailadres*</p>
        <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="Email" required>
        </br>
        <p align="left">Wachtwoord*</p>
        <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required>
        </br>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="group-btn">
            <a  href="accountpagina.php" type="submit" name="inloggen" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Inloggen <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a>
            <br><br><a href="registreren.php">Nog geen account? Maak er een aan</a>
        </span>

        </div>
      </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST;
?>
```

**Next up the accountpage. **

```
<?php
session_start();
include("functieshomepagina.php");
include("header.php");
include("dbconnect.php");


$klantenmail = $_SESSION['email'];
var_dump($_SESSION);
$customer_ID_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM customers WHERE customer_email = '$klantenmail' ");

$customer_ID=[];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($customer_ID_query)){
  $customer_ID[] = $row;
}


//functie voor de account informatie van een specifieke klant voor de accountpagina

$klantenquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, customer_email FROM customers WHERE id = '{$customer_ID[0][0]}'");

$klanten=[];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($klantenquery)){
$klanten[] = $row;
}
//functie voor de account informatie van een specifieke klant voor de bestelling op de accountpagina
$bestellingquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, date_placed, date_paid, total_price, customers_id FROM orders WHERE customers_id = '{$customer_ID[0][0]}'");

$bestelling=[];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($bestellingquery)){
$bestelling[] = $row;

}
?>


  <div align="center">
    <?php logo();?>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid well span6">
    <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2" >
            <img width ='200' src="http://localhost/Avatar_man.png" class="img-circle">
          </div>
          <div class="span8">
              <h3><?php echo $klanten[0][1] ." ".$klanten[0][2] . " ".$klanten[0][3]?></h3>
              <h6>Email: <?php echo $klanten[0][4]    ?></h6>
              <h6>Klanten nummer: <?php echo $klanten[0][0]?></h6>
              <h6></h6>
          </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!--Begin van Bestellingen tabel-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css" type="text/css"/>
  <div class="container">
    <div align="center">
    <h2>Bestellingen</h2>
  </div>


  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-success">
      <tr>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>Datum plaatsen van bestelling</th>
        <th>Datum van betaling</th>
        <th>Totaal prijs</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
        foreach ($bestelling as $key => $value) {
        ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value[0]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value[1]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value[2]?></td>
        <td><?php echo "€ " . number_format($value[3],2)?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

  <?php
  Include("footer.php")
   ?>
```

**So when the customer enters their email I'd like to take that email using session to put it in at the accountpage. Ive seen several methods but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated. **

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your HTML form you have:

```
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST
```

It needs to be:

```
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email']
```

and you need to move that line of code into `homepagina.php` in order for it to capture the session variable. Or you're trying to capture a variable that hasn't been submitted.

You need to reference the name of the input that you want to grab using POST.

Comment: Using var_dump($klantenmail) I found that it stated that it carries "NULL" instead of the email entered.